# Pytorch showing the error: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'zero_'

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, pytorch

I am using Python 3.8 and VSCode.

I tried to create a basic Neural Network without activations and biases but because of the error, I'm not able to update the gradients of the weights.

Matrix Details:

Layer Shape: (1, No. of Neurons)

Weight Layer Shape: (No. of Neurons in the previous layer, No. of Neurons in the next layer)

Here's my code:

```py
# sample neural network

# importing libraries
import torch
import numpy as np
torch.manual_seed(0)

# hyperparameters
epochs = 100
lr = 0.01 # learning rate

# data
X_train = torch.tensor([[1]], dtype = torch.float)
y_train = torch.tensor([[2]], dtype = torch.float)

'''
Network Architecture:
    1 neuron in the first layer
    4 neurons in the second layer
    4 neurons in the third layer
    1 neuron in the last layer

    * I haven't added bias and activation.
'''

# initializing the weights
weights = []
weights.append(torch.rand((1, 4), requires_grad = True))
weights.append(torch.rand((4, 4), requires_grad = True))
weights.append(torch.rand((4, 1), requires_grad = True))

# calculating y_pred
y_pred = torch.matmul(torch.matmul(torch.matmul(X_train, weights[0]), weights[1]), weights[2])

# calculating loss
loss = (y_pred - y_train)**2

# calculating the partial derivatives
loss.backward()

# updating the weights and zeroing the gradients
with torch.no_grad():
    for i in range(len(weights)):
        weights[i] = weights[i] - weights[i].grad
        weights[i].grad.zero_()
```

It it showing the error:

```
File "test3.py", line 43, in <module>
weights[i].grad.zero_()
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'zero_'
```

I don't understand why it is showing this error. Can someone please explain?

Comment: its because  `weights[i].grad` in `weights[i] = weights[i] - weights[i].grad` is of `Nonetype`

Answer (score 1):

Your model doesn't have any trainable parameters for the grad to be calculated. Use torch's Parameter. See this [link](https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/how-could-i-create-a-module-with-learnable-parameters/28115) for creating a module with learnable parameters.

```
  torch.nn.parameter.Parameter
        A kind of Tensor that is to be considered a module parameter.
```